# Existence and unicity of solution for a Cauchy problem

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have this problem $$\begin{cases} y'=-x^2 y^2+\exp(-y^2)\\ y(0)=0\end{cases}$$
the question is: study the existence and unicity of solution for  this problem on $R=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2, |x|\leq \frac12, |y|\leq 1\}$
using two methods.

can someone give me a hint on what is the two methods ?

i have this theorem in the case $y'=f(x,y), y(x_0)=y_0$ if $f$ and $\partial f/\partial y$ are bounded on $R=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2, |x-x_0|\leq a, |y-y_0|\leq b\}$ then the Cauchy problem has a unique solution.

in my case $f(x,y)= -x^2 y^2+\exp(-y^2)$
so from the definition of $R$:  $-\frac14\leq-\frac{y^2}{4}\leq -x^2 y^2\leq 0$
and $\exp(-1)\leq\exp(-y^2)\leq 1$
conclusion $-\frac14+\exp(-1)\leq f(x,y)\leq 1 $ so f is bounded
and i fo the same to $\partial f/\partial y=-2x^2 y-2y\exp(-y^2)$

But what is the second methode ?

Edit:
For the second methods I try to calculate  the iterative  sequence and I can't calculate  it
I found
$y_1(x)=x$
$y_2(x)=- \frac15 x^5+\int_0^x \exp(-s^2)ds$
How to do please
Thank you

Comment: Didn't you already asked this question this morning ?

Comment: i delete it and i edited where is the problem ?

Comment: If if properly remember, you received comments which are no more here and you do not seem to have changed anything to the post. Please, don't do that. Edit your post; that's it. Do not repost. Cheers and *Joyeux Noël !*

Comment: 1 je ne fete pas noel 2 the commant do not help in any thing it says what is study ? if you have an idea post it if not i don't please do not post i don't have time , i want to understand how to solve this exercise that's all thank you

Comment: *Moi non plus !* Now, it is much better.

Comment: You need to show that the solution still exists at $x=\pm\frac12$. The second method could be to apply the proof construction of the Picard-Lindelöf theorem, that is, at least, show that the Picard iteration is defined on the given box.

Comment: @LutzLehmann please how to see that the solutions still exists at =∓12

Comment: You already found that $-\frac14\le y'\le 1$, so that at least $|y(x)|\le|x|$. Thus there is no divergence in finite time.

Comment: i don't understand you "so at least $|y(x)|\leq |x|$" what it means please ?@LutzLehmann

Comment: Please @Lutzlehmann I can't calculate the iterative sequence

Answer (score 1):

I would not call it two methods, just two approaches using the same local existence theorem.

1. As you remarked, the right-side function is smooth on all of $\Bbb R^2$, thus local solutions exist everywhere and can be continued to infinity, be it in $x$ or in $y$. What remains to show is that the solution to the given initial conditions leaves the given box at the sides, not top or bottom.

   This follows trivially from $|f(x,y)|\le M=1$, as then $|y(x)-y(0)|\le M|x-0|$ or $|y(x)|\le |x|$.
2. Using the details of the proof of the existence theorem directly, the Banach fixed-point theorem can be applied to the Picard iteration if the space $X=C([-a,a]\to[-b,b])$ is mapped inside itself. This is the case if $M$ is a bound on $f$ on $[-a,a]\times[-b,b]$ and the inequality $aM\le b$ holds. This is true for the present values. Additionally a Lipschitz constant in $y$ direction needs to exist on this rectangle, this can be applied in different ways to ensure the existence of a solution over $[-a,a]$.

Comment: But we can't  calculate  the iterative sequence it is not a problem?

Comment: No, as the task is not to actually provide the solution, just to show that it exists and is unique.